# UITableView filtered data has incorrect index

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift2

This my code to filter data from my CoreData and it provides the corrected data but if I go to details of the record it gives me the wrong data.

Meaning I have detailed VC that shows a larger image of the camera. So if the index is lets say 1 with the filter data but the real index of the camera in index one is really 20 in CoreData.  How can I correct for this issue?

```
func fetch() {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    // Ref data
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cameras")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locationname == %@", "lobby")
    freq.predicate = predicate
    let fetchResults = try! context.executeFetchRequest(freq) as? [NSManagedObject]
    filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredData = fetchResults!
    searchActive = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Request updated information.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive {
        return filteredData.count
    } else {
    return myData.count
    }
}
```

Next item.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cameraCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! camerasTableViewCell
    if searchActive {
    let data = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text =  data.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.roadName.text = data.valueForKey("locationname") as? String
    let CamImage =  data.valueForKey("dImage") as! NSData
    let CameraImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: CamImage)!
    cell.imageUrl?.image = CameraImage
    } else {
        let data = myData[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text =  data.valueForKey("name") as? String
        cell.roadName.text = data.valueForKey("locationname") as? String
        let CamImage =  data.valueForKey("dImage") as! NSData
        let CameraImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: CamImage)!
        cell.imageUrl?.image = CameraImage
    }
    return cell
}
```

Next item

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! largeCameraViewController
    vc.row = selectedIndexPath.row

}
```

Comment: Please can you post your table view datasource methods (particularly `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and the code that presents/segues to the detail VC.  It sounds like you need to amend the present/segue code to use filteredData (if searchActive is true) to locate the correct object to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the object itself in `prepareForSegue`, not the row.  Add a property to your `LargeCameraViewController`:

```
var camera : NSManagedObject?
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`, obtain the `camera` from the relevant row of either `filteredData` or `myData`, depending on whether `searchActive` is true or false:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! largeCameraViewController
    if (searchActive) {
        vc.camera = filteredData[selectedIndexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
    } else {
        vc.camera = myData[selectedIndexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
    }
}
```

Then in `LargeCameraViewController` you can access the relevant attributes from the `camera` NSManagedObject.

Comment: Thanks so much I have been struggling for months over how to get search bar and filtered data to work!!!